# Creating a function with a FUN input in r

Tags: r, function

I am looking to make a function where the user can enter their own model selection function as an input to be used. I'm having trouble with finding the answer as I keep getting search results about how to make a simple R function, as opposed to an input much like the apply family.

Here is an example similar to what I am looking for but not quite:

```
simple<- function(mod, FUN){
  switch(FUN,
         AIC = AIC(mod),
         BIC = BIC(mod))
}
simple(lm(rnorm(100) ~ rnorm(100,4)), "AIC")
```

The above code runs but I must plan for all of the possible functions and write them within switch. I also am forced to write "AIC" as opposed to simply AIC.

Any thoughts to how I can create the function I am looking for? Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: I think you're looking for `match.fun()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
simple<- function(mod, FUN){
  FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
  FUN(mod)
}

simple(lm(rnorm(100) ~ rnorm(100,4)),FUN =  "BIC")
```

`match.fun` accepts a function, symbol or character, so there is some flexibility in how the `FUN` argument is passed.

An option for passing multiple functions, as mentioned in the comments:

```
simple <- function(mod, FUN){
  FUNS <- lapply(FUN,match.fun)
  lapply(FUNS,function(fun) fun(mod))
}
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for. It works with BIC unquoted which is what I was looking at. Much appreciate. Will mark as answered soon.

Comment: @EvanFriedland Tip for future problem solving: you correctly knew that you wanted to do something like what the *apply functions do. Start typing `lapply`, `sapply`, `apply` at the console and look at the first line of those functions. ;)

Comment: @joran, But in this case, you can only pass one FUN at a time.. Either "AIC" or "BIC", what about if I needed to pass both `FUN= c("AIC", "BIC")` ? i tried and got error.